# UPS Shipping API Error - The ShipFrom country must be the same as the Shipper country

Tags: postman, ups, ups-api

hope you all are doing great. It's my first time using UPS APIs and I am trying to create a test shipment in postman using UPS shipping test API but i am getting this error:

```
{
    "response": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "120317",
                "message": "The ShipFrom country must be the same as the Shipper country"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have downloaded the shipping developer kit and read the documentation but I can't find the error code or any solution in the documentation.

It let me create shipments from Pakistan to US through UPS CampusShip platform.

My shipper's account country is US and I want to create shipment from Pakistan to US or any other country to US.

Is it possible to create shipment with ShipFrom country different from Shipper country? or Is their any other API to create import/export shipment?

Resource Links:

- [UPS Shipping API Documentation](https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/Shipment)
- [UPS Developer Kit](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US)

Comment: You failed to show us your minimal reproducible example code. Also, this isn't the sort of question that S.O. can really help with. You should pose this question in the UPS discussion forums dedicated to its API. Also, given your use of "ShipFrom" and "Shipper" it looks like you are trying to send an item from a country different than the country associated with your "Shipper" account. That is unlikely to be allowed without special authorization. I certainly wouldn't allow it if I were creating the UPS API.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it on the UPS discussion forum. Thanks.